# Unable to connect Android ADB over TCP/IP

Tags: android, tcp, adb

I'm trying to get the Android Debug Bridge working over wifi from my 64-bit Windows 7 desktop computer to my Nexus10.  I connect the device over USB, and then I followed "[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp), but I end up with an error message that it can't connect:

```
C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools>adb usb
restarting in USB mode

C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
R32D300NXJV            device product:mantaray model:Nexus_10 device:manta


C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools>adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 192.168.231.2
unable to connect to 192.168.231.2:5555
```

To start debugging this, I tried pinging the Nexus10 from my desktop computer.  Both devices are connected to the same router, by a cable in the case of the desktop computer,  and wirelessly for the Nexus10.  However, I got

```
C:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools>ping 192.168.231.2

Pinging 192.168.231.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.231.61: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.231.61: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.231.61: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.231.61: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.231.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

The IP address 192.168.231.61 which returns "Destination host unreachable" is the IP address of my desktop computer.  Although the ping doesn't work, I don't know whether the fact that I can't ping is the source of my ADB problem or whether it's unconnected to the issue.

I'm running Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31.  Can anyone help?

Comment: did you checked adb over network?
you can find it in developer option,check it，or if you cannot find the option,you should install third app to support.
and you can use adb connect ip:port

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This must have been a networking problem, because when I connected via a wireless network on a different subnet, then (1) I was able to ping the nexus10 from my desktop, and (2) ADB connected over TCPIP OK. So my conclusion is that my desktop/router/nexus10 had some bizarre routing incompatibility when on the same subnet, when disappeared when they were on different subnets.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: I had to restart my Router in order to get it worked. Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

I have problems both with my nexus 4 and my nexus 10 on the same wifi as my laptop. The nexus 4 I have had more time to experiment with, and what helps is either rebooting the phone, or using "DNS Hostname Changer" to restart networking and then I can connect again.

The Nexus 10 seems to be a bit worse than Nexus 4 though....